# Upgraded from Ubuntu Studio 18.10 to 19.04. Do I need to install Backports PPA?

Tags: 19.04, do-release-upgrade

I had a rock solid Ubuntu Studio 18.10 on one of my laptops and I did the "sudo do-release-upgrade" and it upgraded to 19.04.  My question is do I need to add the "Backports PPA" which is suggested for Ubuntu Studio 18.04 installs or is it already on my system now?  The upgrade process went perfectly by the way!  Thanks Ubuntu Studio for the great work!

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to, but if you want you can.

In UbuntuStudio 18.04 it is neccessary to have this ppa installed to extend the support period to 3 years, 18.04 came with a support period of only 9 month, contrary to the normal LTS support period of 3 years.

The support period of 19.04 is 9 month and is not going to be extended, it's not an LTS release.

You can take a look at the [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntustudio-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports?field.series_filter=disco) to see which packages this repository contains.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!